# How to access array inside a json objectin react js

Tags: json, reactjs

I am trying to access a array inside json object. This is my json file.

```
{
"items": [
    {
        "createTime": "2019-10-25T04:33:50.238Z",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "name": "xxx.pdf",
                "legal": false,
                "id": "1908925450",
                "abc": true,
                "def": true
            },
            {
                "name": "xxx_original.xml",
                "legal": true,
                "id": "1908925449",
                "abc": false,
                "def": false
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

I access the details contains here using following code

```
    const {
        items = [],
        attachmentList = items.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.attachments),
        attachmentName = attachmentList.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.name),
        createTime = items.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.createTime),
    } = data;
```

I can get the value for createTime, but I cannot get attachmentName,  it returns empty ? Why it is not possible to get values from attachments

Comment: is this that you want ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58553030/6544460

Comment: @VahidAkhtar I want a way to access the data.  Because i am accessing the attachmentList as the same way I access items array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your attachments are array and doing

`attachmentList.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.name),`

is failing as attachmentList contains array of arrays and item is an array.

Try using [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), it will flatten the array of array (attachments) to array of attachments.

Checkout the snippet

```js
var data = {
  "items": [{
    "createTime": "2019-10-25T04:33:50.238Z",
    "attachments": [{
        "name": "xxx.pdf",
        "legal": false,
        "id": "1908925450",
        "abc": true,
        "def": true
      },
      {
        "name": "xxx_original.xml",
        "legal": true,
        "id": "1908925449",
        "abc": false,
        "def": false
      }
    ]
  }]
}


const {
  items = [],
    attachmentList = items.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.attachments).flat(),
    attachmentName = attachmentList.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.name),
    createTime = items.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.createTime),
} = data;

console.log(attachmentName)
```

Answer (score 0):

`items.slice(0, 1)` will return an new Array. So when you use map, `attachmentList` will return an Array in Array like this:

```
[{…}]
   0:
      attachments: (2) [{…}, {…}]
      createTime: "2019-10-25T04:33:50.238Z"
```

First you you can refactor like this:

```
const {
        items = [],
        attachmentList = items.slice(0, 1)[0].map(item => item.attachments), 
        // Access to the first item with return of items.slice(0, 1)
        attachmentName = attachmentList.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.name),
        createTime = items.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.createTime),
    } = data;
```

Or:

```
const {
        items = [],
        attachmentList = items.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.attachments),
        attachmentName = attachmentList[0].slice(0, 1).map(item => item.name),
        // Access to the first item of attachmentList
        createTime = items.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.createTime),
    } = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your attchmentList is an array of arrays now, you can do this to get name

```
const {
    items = [],
    attachmentList = items.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.attachments),
    attachmentName = attachmentList.slice(0, 1).map((item, i) => item[i].name),
    createTime = items.slice(0, 1).map(item => item.createTime),
} = data;
```

Hope it helps